# Getting Objective-C Objects in PHP

Tags: php, objective-c, object

I am sending an NSData Object to the server script running PHP.Is it possible to collect that object in PHP ?
  Is it possible to get NSArray,NSString, NSData or any Custom Objects (Subclass of NSObject) in PHP ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for a method for serializing and deserializing your data.

Facebook uses a protocol called [Thrift](http://incubator.apache.org/thrift/) Google uses [protocol buffers.](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/)

If you don't need to have an industry standard solution, you can come up with your own way to tag values with meta data in order to determine how PHP will handle your data.  PHP doesn't (at least that I'm aware of) have all the niftness that objective C has with its objects and inheritance, but PHP has a function or library for almost anything you will need to do.

One approach might be to use JSON to store type/value pair for each parameter you want to process.